# Set algebra identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a paper and in it, they used this identity. For any set $A$, $B$ in $X$ we have:

$$A = B \cup (A \cap B^c)$$

Now I know $A \subset B \cup (A \cap B^c)$, but it appears to me $B \cup (A \cap B^c) = A \cup B$.

Comment: You are right: $B \cup (A \cap B^c) = A \cup B$ is true, but $B \cup (A \cap B^c) = A $ is not true.

Comment: It is fine if either (1) you add the hypothesis $B \subseteq A$, or (2) you adjust it slightly to $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$, or (3) we adjust the left side to $A \cup B$, as you suggested.

Comment: Either $A=\varnothing$ or $B=X$ for instance are easy counterexamples. $A$ strictly included in $B$ also lead to contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect.
Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and
$$A=\emptyset \text{ and } B=\{1,2\}$$
Then
$$B\cup (A\cap B^c)$$
$$=B\cup \emptyset=B \ne\emptyset $$